# Помогите разобраться с Pivot

Tags: c#, uwp

У меня получился во такой вот Header у `Pivot`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно чтобы он был похож на такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е все трудности связаны с изменением стиля `Pivot`. Нужно:

- чтобы это поле было одинаково поделено на 3 ячейки в которых будут эти `PivotItem` (Лента чат Настройки)
- изменить цвет с черного на белый
- рисовать внизу линию выбранного меню.

Пока ни с чем разобраться не получается даже тупо цвет текста сменить... Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: @andreycha: Хм, а где в WPF `Pivot`?

Comment: @VladD если говорить именно о контроле, то такой есть в WP, например. Тут, похоже, автор просто пытается добиться похожего look&feel, явно используя XAML дизайнер. Возможно, стоит сменить на [tag:xaml].

Comment: @andreycha: Ага, или возможно [tag:uwp].

Comment: @VladD Это не WPF а UWP, приношу извинения)

Answer (score 1):

О, я помню сколько потратил времени на попытки сделать табы из пивота.
Вот тут https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot есть пример табов. Вся суть в кастомизации стилей. А чтобы полоски добавить надо с помощью визуальных состояний в стиле добавлять нижний бордер к активному элементу. У меня получилось сделать такие же табы, как в звонилке. Жаль, что не пригодилось.

Comment: Я ооочень долго штудировал этот пример... До кона так и не понял за что части xaml отвечают. Но там сделано не совсем как мне нужно. Табы там находятся тупо по центру. И не делят свободное место на равные ячейки. Т.е если убрать равнение по центру, то они все прижмутся к левой стороне...

Comment: Там же в стиле написан комментарий что сделано чтобы табы были по центру. Надо изменить грид с табами и всё. Там стоит вроде `* auto *`, а надо сделать `* * *`

Comment: Точнее надо сделать `auto * auto` и как-то поменять размеры табов, чтобы они растягивались. Пока не понял как.